# Using karate.set to change value of an array

Tags: karate

I want to change the values present in an array using karate.set as i am using it in if condition
my code is:

```
> * def name = ["ankit"]
> * def value = 2
> * eval if ( value == 2) karate.set('name', 'ANKIT_DESAI')
```

but the value of name is not changing

Answer (score 2):

Assume that as a list and modify value based on index

```
* def name = ["ankit"]
* def value = 2
* eval if ( value == 2) name[0] = "ANKIT_DESAI"
```